# Access Denied for User 'username'@'IP' error - digtal ocean

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, digital-ocean, lamp

I've currently set up a staging area for my app in Digital Ocean with LAMP stack. The Framework for my app is Laravel 5.5 and Vue 2x.

In development, I've been using remote MySQL and had no issues with the connection error. However, when I moved it to the staging env, it is giving me access denied error. When I looked at it closely to the error log, Access denied is for username@[digital-ocean-droplet-ip], whereas I have properly configured the MySQL credentials to the remote host IP under laravel's config/database file.

So, I am doubtful if I have to do any configuration under Apache to allow any external MySQL connection? I forgot the cmd but I did allow sfw firewall allow to any port 3306 to the remote server IP address in Apache.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to connect mysql locally. I mean are you able to connect mysql from droplet itself?

Comment: @WebArtisan, no i have not setup any mysql db in the droplet

Answer (score 1):

MySQL by default does not create an user with access from remote connections.

First you need to create an user on database that allows connection from outside (%) or a specific IP

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Than give him privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'%';
```

> The *s could be replaced by your database and table name respectively

You might also check if in your mysql configuration(/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf in my case) has this line uncommented

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

Change the ip if necessary

restart mysql and apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service mysql restart
```

Than update the user and password at your .env file and try again!